# Simulating from VECM to VAR in statsmodels

Tags: simulation, vector-autoregression, statsmodels, vector-error-correction-model

I need to simulate from a VECM in Python. My VECM doesn't have constants nor linear trends (this holds true for both inside and outside the cointegration matrix). However, the [statsmodels VECM](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html#vecm) doesn't have a `simulate_vecm()` method. On the contrary, the [Vector Autoregressions (VAR)](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html#var) has a [`simulate_var()`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARResults.simulate_var.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARResults.simulate_var) method. By inspecting the source code, it turns out that [`VARResults.simulate_var()`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARResults.simulate_var.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VARResults.simulate_var) calls a function from [`statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.util.py`](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/159d8dd62e1911e4fd36d1a05269b88cea5e9e56/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/util.py) called `varsim(coefs, intercept, sig_u, steps=100, initial_values=None, seed=None, nsimulations=None)`. Since a VECM is nothing but a VAR whose coefficients matrices are properly transformed to accommodate for cointegration, my strategy to simulate from a VECM would be to:

1. get `VECMResults.var_rep` member after the fit. This should encompass the VAR representation of the VECM. Let's call this output `coefs`.
2. call `varsim(coefs=coefs, intercept=None, sig_u=None, steps=100)`.

Could you please confirm that this is correct to simulate from my VECM given the constant terms specification and the VAR representation got through the VECM fit? I would really appreciate it if you could also provide a small script to exemplify your answer.